# Why does SEMrush report lots of backlinks from the 301 redirected old website to the new one?

Tags: 301-redirect, backlinks, seo-audit, semrush

The old version of the website is `http://example.com` and they 301 redirected it to the new URL, `https://example.se`.

I was checking the domain in SEMrush and it was 2.8k backlinks from the old website to the new one. How is it possible? Is it due to a technical issue?

Comment: A 301 redirect is a type of "backlink", so SEMrush is not necessarily wrong in this respect.